# Service worker: What to return if no network, and cache miss for a static resource (caching strategy)

Tags: service-worker

I have various caching strategies, .e.g.

A `GET` for a page: Try network, then cache, else a default page.

However if it is a static resource like a `.css` or `.js` file. What should one return if it fails to get a response from the network? If it is not obtained within 4s I know the system is down, and a long timedout out fetch is not ideal.

At the moment I return a `404`, but semantically this is not quite right, its not that the resource was not found, it was that the request never got to the server. But it seems like the most applicable `4XX` series (client failure) code to me.

```js
    get404Response(statusText = "") {
        const init = { status: 404, statusText: statusText };
        return new Response("", init);
    }
```

Alternatively I don't want to raise a fetch error, because in the chrome dev tools, under application for the service worker, it tracks how many errors your SW has raised, and I am trying to keep track of legitamate errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a judgment call, and I don't think you're going to get a definitive answer.

My first preference would be to use [`Response.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/error), though you mentioned that you're wary of logging noise in DevTools. Synthetically creating a `Response.error()` comes closest to matching the behavior you'd see if you let the request time out on its own.

If you would prefer to return a "valid" (non-error) response but aren't happy with using a `404` status code, then using a [`503`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) might be an alternative? I'm not sure that you're going to see any functional difference worth worrying about, though.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the solid insight, that is a great help! `Response.error()` sounds like they way to mimic the browser. And 503 is a great description, but sounds a little like the server is at fault from than the client. I guess the codes are designed for server responses (in a time before service workers, and not applicable to).

Answer (score 0):

504 seems like a good fit:
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

> 504 Gateway Timeout
> The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

I stumped across it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache#value

If one requests a cached response with `only-if-cached`, and there is no cached response, then the brower returns a 504.